# Advanced SQL query to select distinct data

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables that I need to extract data from.
Table1 (t1) and sample values:

```
| rq_id | user_id | is_good |  
|----- 1     |---- 223     |--------      0  ----   |  
|----- 3     |---- 223     |--------      1   ----  |  
|----- 4     |---- 239     |--------      0   ----  |  
|----- 5     |---- 223     |--------      0   ----  |
```

Table2 (t2) and sample values:

```
| rq_id | version | random_content |  
|---1---|---3------|------A------|    
|---1---|---2------|------B------|    
|---1---|---1------|------C------|  
|---3---|---2------|------D------|  
|---3---|---1------|------F------|  
|---5---|---2------|------X------|  
|---5---|---1------|------W------|
```

In Table1 rq_id is unique, in table2 there are multiple rows with the same rq_id.
I need to get 1 row per rq_id from Table2 (only the one with the highest version). The criteria to select the request_ids from Table2 would come from Table1 where user_id=223 and is_good="0".
So in this case, I would like it to return:
`|---1---|---3------|------A------|` and
`|---5---|---2------|------X------|`.

Can this be done in one fast SQL query with some joints and distinct selects/inner selects or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.rq_ID = b.rq_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  rq_id, MAX(version) max_ver
            FROM    table2
            GROUP   BY rq_id
        ) c ON  b.rq_ID = c.rq_ID AND
                b.version = c.max_ver
WHERE   a.user_ID = 223 AND a.is_good = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/954d2/2)